# Performance between doc.querySelectorAll('#id element') vs doc.querySelector('#id').querySelectorAll('element');

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

I'm trying to find an element with:

```
doc.querySelectorAll('#divContentList article');
```

It work well, but another developer told me I should write:

```
doc.querySelector('#divContentList').querySelectorAll('article');
```

He said this is better because it go direct to `#divContentList` and then look for `article` elements.

I don't think his solution is the best in speed performance and it search the element twice.
I thought `querySelectorAll` is awesome enough to do its job.

Main question is, which line of code is the best overall?

Comment: Has either of you *tested* the code?

Comment: You should definitely test it, but `doc.querySelector('#divContentList')` will definitely will be slower than `#getElementById()`.

Comment: This almost certainly isn't the slowest thing in your application. Don't worry about it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would use `getElementById` if possible.  See this test case: http://jsperf.com/selector-tests-jm

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [Mauricio Soares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1347129/mauricio-soares) with his jsPerf first example:

```html
<div id="divContentList">
    <article></article>
</div>
```

Would indeed the first method:
`doc.querySelectorAll('#divContentList article');`
faster if there is only ONE `article` in it.

I have modified jsPerf from to 10, then to 1000 `article`’s, the performance differences are dramatic. [Check it here](http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-perf-test/2)

```html
<div id="divContentList">
    <article></article>
    ...
    <article></article>
</div>
```

This will result that second method on my question:
`doc.querySelector('#divContentList').querySelectorAll('article');`
is much faster

And last, the one by using `getElementById` the performance increases slightly more.
`doc.getElementById('divContentList').querySelectorAll('article');`
That the best performance

[Keith Rousseau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66330/keith-rousseau) got right that `querySelectorAll` evaluates from right to left.

**Edit**:

Also I found out something different about `querySelector` and `getElementById/getElementsByTagName`. querySelector returns Static NodeList, while getElementById returns Live NodeList.

I made another [test](http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-perf-test/4)
`document.getElementById('divContentList').getElementsByTagName('article');`
This one takes the cake. The difference is ridiculous

Comment: I updated the test case with `articles` that are not in `#divContentList`. If the qsa evaluates from right to left I would expect the single qsa to be (much) slower, but it's not. How can we explain this?

Comment: Not sure how to explain this @Halcyon. I've heard 4 months ago that browsers reads CSS right-to-left. So for qsa, is for me a confirmation that it does too. Which means the way you write your CSS (thinking left-to-right) was so actually bad CSS and have an impact in performance. So having more than 2 CSS selectors is actually bad. Or defining html tag such as `section` || `.main .section` instead of `.main-section`. Makes me think a single selector rules them all.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is either:

- Method 1 is faster
- Method 2 is faster
- There is no difference

The issue is that the answer might change over time. Browser vendors tend to optimize methods that are used a lot. If method 1 is used a lot it will likely be faster, or be faster in the future.

Both methods seem equal to me (with the given input). If there is a fundamental underlying reason why one should be faster: use the faster method.

---

Since your first match is an id there can always only be one match.

If your query was `".parent .child"` and there are many parents that have no children then `".parent .child"` would *probably* be faster than `(".parent").qsa(".child")`.

Comment: Seems there is a difference between these methods.

Comment: This answer boils down to "I'm not sure if one method is faster, but if one is, then you should use that." - which isn't all that helpful.

Answer (score 1):

querySelectorAll evaluates from right to left so the first one will find all articles on the page and then filter that down to just those underneath divContentList. I would do getElementById for the id and then find the articles underneath.

But as others have said, test it. And test it in multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jsPerf for this kind of tests...

I've set up a simple performance test with your use case [here](http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-perf-test), and it seems that they have a similar performance, the "single" querySelector seems to be a little bit more performatic some times, but I don't think this is gonna be a problem at all in your application.

Comment: Hey thanks for that link. You're awesome! This will mean there is a difference. Writing first method is smaller than second method. In this case using an `#id` and `tagname`.

Comment: yup, that probably will change according to selector complexity, and how many elements you have in the DOM. :)

Answer (score 0):

Granted, this is an old question, but stumbled across this & felt like weighing in. One big note ahead of time, which I don't think anyone else delved into, is: those two statements aren't *technically* synonymous. This may explain the general performance difference.

The easiest example of this is actually YouTube. If you go to any video, you'll find that they actually repeat the ID, `#content`.  In the first video I tried, after loading the comments section, `document.querySelectorAll("#content")` actually returned about 20 elements. This is not to standard, and the [W3's HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) will actually tell you this is invalid HTML. However, *browsers still permit this*, rather than straight-up rejecting or modifying the HTML.

If your site had repeated usages of `#divContentList`, your statement would return all of the article elements from within all of them; whereas your coworker's would only return articles nested within the the *first* instance of `#divContentList` that it found. This may explain why your coworkers appears to generally be faster (see below). And like most people've already pointed out, replacing his/her first `querySelector` with `getElementById` would likely be even faster across all browsers.

---

Beyond that, I agree with the general idea that, "if you want to know the performance of something: just measure it." but be careful with how you construct your tests. [Here's an example where the JS engine optimized out the actual test case](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2015AprJun/0394.html). My advice is always test within the context of your actual use-case. There have been threads talking about how `element.querySelector` [can actually be slower than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430923/why-document-queryselector-is-more-efficient-than-element-queryselector) `document.querySelector`; however, from brief recent testing, I could not replicate this.

Using IDs / classes like `#sidebar` and `.question-hyperlink` on this page itself, in all cases `document.querySelector('<ID>').querySelectorAll('<CLASS>');` outperformed `document.querySelectorAll('<ID> <CLASS>');`.

However, and I feel like this is critical, the difference was never more than ~10-20%. At a certain point the question becomes, "is the trade-off between readability / writeability vs performance worthwhile". If you're only running this statement one or two times, *the difference is likely in the order of microseconds*. For a general use-case, either your original statement or your coworker's would be fine.

And one final note,

> I don't think his solution is the best in speed performance and it search the element twice

If you felt like a bit of reading, you could look into how browsers actually implement these lookup methods for webpages. Looking at the Firefox source, what you'll find is "getElementById" uses a hashtable lookup, which makes it nearly instantaneous to find a result. The implementation will vary between vendors, which is why it can be important that you test your site on many different browsers.